# Jump To Option on Key Press in ngbDropDown

Tags: select, dropdown, ng-bootstrap

The default **select** html tag has a nice fuctionality of jumping to best matching option on key press (i.e. if I press 'a' it jumps to first option starting with that letter).

Is there any way to replicate this functionality in **ngbDropdown** directive?

I have tried by adding the **ngbDropdownItem** on each option but that only helps with up and down navigation via keyboard.